# Save attachments to folder based on the first characters of the file name

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

This script auto-prints attachments.

I'd like to also save the attachments to a folder based on the first characters of the filename.

I receive work orders in email in .docx format that always begin with four digits *(e.g. 1200‑john_doe‑job1)*.
There are characters after those four digit work order numbers like client name and job descriptions.

Folders are broken up into the following:
The root folder is constant, "C:\work orders"
Inside this folder work orders are broken up into large folders by work orders 1200-1299, 1300-1399, 1400-1499 etc.
The script would need to take the first two characters of the .docx file, and navigate to the appropriate large folder, and then into it's specific subfolder.

Result I am trying to achieve:
Work order .docx file that begins with 1256 would navigate into the 1200-1299 folder (C:\work orders\1200-1299), and then be saved into folder 1256-randomtext (C:\work orders\1200-1299\1256-randomtext).

```vb
Public Declare Function GetProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
  ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
  ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
                  
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
  Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
  ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
  ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
                  
Sub MessageAndAttachmentProcessor(Item As Outlook.MailItem, _
  Optional bolPrintMsg As Boolean, _
  Optional bolSaveMsg As Boolean, _
  Optional bolPrintAtt As Boolean, _
  Optional bolSaveAtt As Boolean, _
  Optional bolInsertLink As Boolean, _
  Optional strAttFileTypes As String, _
  Optional strFolderPath As String, _
  Optional varMsgFormat As OlSaveAsType, _
  Optional strPrinter As String)
                     
    Dim olkAttachment As Outlook.Attachment, _
      objFSO As FileSystemObject, _
      strMyPath As String, _
      strExtension As String, _
      strFileName As String, _
      strOriginalPrinter As String, _
      strLinkText As String, _
      strRootFolder As String, _
      strTempFolder As String, _
      varFileType As Variant, _
      intCount As Integer, _
      intIndex As Integer, _
      arrFileTypes As Variant
                  
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strTempFolder = Environ("TEMP") & "\"
                      
    If strAttFileTypes = "" Then
        arrFileTypes = Array("*")
    Else
        arrFileTypes = Split(strAttFileTypes, ",")
    End If
    
    If bolPrintMsg Or bolPrintAtt Then
        If strPrinter <> "" Then
            strOriginalPrinter = GetDefaultPrinter()
            SetDefaultPrinter strPrinter
        End If
    End If
                      
    If bolSaveMsg Or bolSaveAtt Then
        If strFolderPath = "" Then
            strRootFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents\"
        Else
            strRootFolder = strFolderPath & IIf(Right(strFolderPath, 1) = "\", "", "\")
        End If
    End If
                      
    If bolSaveMsg Then
        Select Case varMsgFormat
            Case olHTML
                strExtension = ".html"
            Case olMSG
                strExtension = ".msg"
            Case olRTF
                strExtension = ".rtf"
            Case olDoc
                strExtension = ".doc"
            Case olTXT
                strExtension = ".txt"
            Case Else
                strExtension = ".msg"
        End Select
        Item.SaveAs strRootFolder & RemoveIllegalCharacters(Item.Subject) & strExtension, varMsgFormat
    End If
                          
    For intIndex = Item.Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olkAttachment = Item.Attachments.Item(intIndex)
        'Print the attachments if requested'
        If bolPrintAtt Then
            If olkAttachment.Type <> olEmbeddeditem Then
                For Each strFileType In arrFileTypes
                    If (strFileType = "*") Or (LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(olkAttachment.FileName)) = LCase(strFileType)) Then
                        olkAttachment.SaveAsFile strTempFolder & olkAttachment.FileName
                        ShellExecute 0&, "print", strTempFolder & olkAttachment.FileName, 0&, 0&, 0&
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
        'Save the attachments if requested'
        If bolSaveAtt Then
            strFileName = olkAttachment.FileName
            intCount = 0
            Do While True
                strMyPath = strRootFolder & strFileName
                If objFSO.FileExists(strMyPath) Then
                    intCount = intCount + 1
                    strFileName = "Copy (" & intCount & ") of " & olkAttachment.FileName
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            olkAttachment.SaveAsFile strMyPath
            If bolInsertLink Then
                If Item.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
                    strLinkText = strLinkText & "<a href=""file://" & strMyPath & """>" & olkAttachment.FileName & "</a><br>"
                Else
                    strLinkText = strLinkText & strMyPath & vbCrLf
                End If
                olkAttachment.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
                      
    If bolPrintMsg Then
        Item.PrintOut
    End If
                      
    If bolPrintMsg Or bolPrintAtt Then
        If strOriginalPrinter <> "" Then
            SetDefaultPrinter strOriginalPrinter
        End If
    End If
                      
    If bolInsertLink Then
        If Item.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
            Item.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody & "<br><br>Removed Attachments<br><br>" & strLinkText
        Else
            Item.Body = Item.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Removed Attachments" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strLinkText
        End If
        Item.Save
    End If
                  
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set olkAttachment = Nothing
End Sub
                  
Function GetDefaultPrinter() As String
    Dim strPrinter As String, _
      intReturn As Integer
    strPrinter = Space(255)
    intReturn = GetProfileString("Windows", ByVal "device", "", strPrinter, Len(strPrinter))
    If intReturn Then
        strPrinter = UCase(Left(strPrinter, InStr(strPrinter, ",") - 1))
    End If
    GetDefaultPrinter = strPrinter
End Function
                  
Function RemoveIllegalCharacters(strValue As String) As String
    ' Purpose: Remove characters that cannot be in a filename from a string.'
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = strValue
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "<", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, ">", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, ":", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, Chr(34), "'")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "/", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "\", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "|", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "?", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "*", "")
End Function

Sub SetDefaultPrinter(strPrinterName As String)
    Dim objNet As Object
    Set objNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
    objNet.SetDefaultPrinter strPrinterName
    Set objNet = Nothing
End Sub
                  
Sub Autoprint(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    MessageAndAttachmentProcessor Item, False, False, True, False, False, "doc,docx"
End Sub
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code, but what specific problem are you having with implementing what you describe?

Comment: @TimWilliams that's the script im running which has the capability to save files, i just have no idea how to implement routing rules into the program to save it in a specific folder as described above. i'm not sure if it'd be easier to just create a brand new script to do this one single task, but maybe that would be a better way to go rather than editing this one. im very new to VBA, most of my experience is in javascript.

Comment: Will the folder structure already exists (both the group folder such as "1200-1299" and the individual child folder such as "1256 some text here") ?  What should happen if they're not found?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - added example of using the function to save attachments.

I would create a separate function to return the folder path, and create any missing folders as needed.

For example:

```
Sub TestAttachmentSave()
    Dim selItems As Selection
    Dim objItem As Object, att As Attachment
    Dim savepath As String, attName As String

    Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection 'all selected mails
    
    For Each objItem In selItems
        If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then       'is mail object?
            For Each att In objItem.Attachments  'check any attachments
                attName = att.FileName
                If LCase(attName) Like "####*.doc*" Then 'candidate for saving?
                    savepath = GetSaveLocation(attName)
                    If Len(savepath) > 0 Then            'got a path to save to?
                        att.SaveAsFile savepath & attName
                        Debug.Print "Saved", savepath & attName
                    End If
                End If
            Next att
        End If
    Next objItem
End Sub


'Return folder path for filenames of format [four digits]+[optional other text]
'  create any missing folders as needed
Function GetSaveLocation(attName As String) As String
    Const ROOT_FOLDER As String = "C:\Temp\work orders\" 'must already exist
    Dim dd As String, pth As String, fldrGrp As String, f
    If attName Like "####*" Then 'begins with 4 digits?
        dd = Left(attName, 2)
        fldrGrp = dd & "00-" & dd & "99\"
        pth = ROOT_FOLDER & fldrGrp
        
        If Len(Dir(pth, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir pth 'create group folder if needed
        
        'any matching
        f = Dir(pth & Left(attName, 4) & "*", vbDirectory)
        If Len(f) > 0 Then
            GetSaveLocation = pth & f & "\" 'existing folder
        Else
            GetSaveLocation = pth & Left(attName, 4) & "\"
            MkDir GetSaveLocation 'create final folder
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: i've posted an answer below with what i've got, i seem to be unable to get the attachment name as a string, and input it into the function you wrote above in order to return the path i need to save the file into.

Comment: "i seem to be unable to get the attachment name as a string" - what happens when it reaches that line?  Does it error, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

here's what i've got, but it keeps returning an error trying to implement it... google has been no help on the error for my line attName = oAttachment.DisplayName.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
Dim attName As String
attName = oAttachment.DisplayName
sSaveFolder = GetSaveLocation(attName)
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName

End Sub
'Return folder path for filenames of format [four digits]+[optional other text]
'  create any missing folders as needed
Function GetSaveLocation(attName As String) As String
    Const ROOT_FOLDER As String = "C:\work orders\" 'must already exist
    Dim dd As String, pth As String, fldrGrp As String, f
    If attName Like "####*" Then 'begins with 4 digits?
        dd = Left(attName, 2)
        fldrGrp = dd & "00-" & dd & "99\"
        pth = ROOT_FOLDER & fldrGrp
        
        If Len(Dir(pth, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir pth 'create group folder if needed
        
        'any matching
        f = Dir(pth & Left(attName, 4) & "*", vbDirectory)
        If Len(f) > 0 Then
            GetSaveLocation = pth & f & "\" 'existing folder
        Else
            GetSaveLocation = pth & Left(attName, 4) & "\"
            MkDir GetSaveLocation 'create final folder
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You're missing something like `Set oAttachment = MItem.Attachments(1)`  As posted, `oAttachment` is Nothing when you try to read its `DisplayName`

Comment: @TimWilliams i've added the line `Set oAttachment = MItem.Attachments(1)` above my line `attName = oAttachment.DisplayName` to set the attachment, but still comes up with the error "Object variable or With block variable not set" on the `attName = oAttachment.DisplayName` Line

Comment: Please update your post if you make code changes.  How are you calling `SaveAttachmentsToDisk` ?    FYI  `oAttachment.FileName` (not displayname) is probably more useful here.

Comment: See my updated answer below.  That should give you some idea of how to incorporate the function.

Comment: This space is for answers. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77566036/edit) the question.